# Two queries with different condition and result set into one table

Tags: php, mysql

How to write either mysql query or two diffrent queries with different result set can be converted into one array for a single table?

I have one table t1:

```
date            company     product      sales
------------------------------------------------
2013-12-01      abc         a1           100
2014-12-01      abc         b1           50
2014-12-01      abc         c1           100
2014-12-01      xyz         x1           100

Query1 (based on selection of date='2014-12-01'):
--------------------------------------------------------

select company, sum(sales) as day_sales from t1 where date='2014-12-01' 
group by company;

will give:

company   day_sales
---------------------------
abc       150
xyz       100

Query2 (based on selection of date between '2014-12-01' and '2013-12-31'):
--------------------------------------------------------

select company, sum(sales) as previous_year_month_sale from t1 
where date between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-31' group by company;

will give:

company   previous_year_month_sale
-----------------------------------
abc       100
```

How can i combine both results into one table like:

```
company   day_sales   previous_year_mtd
-----------------------------------------
abc       150         100
xyz       100           0
```

Please suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: use [`union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Mr. Strawberry, we met again, I applied the CASE syntax but again it's consuming too much time around 19mins. I have indexing on date, company. Should i need to put indexing on day_sales?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sales = array();
```

In the query 1 results loop add this:

```
$sales $row['company'][0] = $row['day_sales'] ;
```

In the query 2 results loop add this:

```
$sales $row['company'][1] = $row['previous_year_month_sale'] ;
```

Output

```
foreach ($sales as $company => $val){
  echo "$company  $val[0]    $val[2] \n";
}
```

Comment: The code is untested but should work, if not you should get the general idea.